# Best practices for unit tests on custom functions for a drake workflow

Tags: drake-r-package

A drake workflow can have several custom functions stored in its R directory.  It would make sense to develop unit tests for the custom functions.  There is well-established tooling and structures for running testthat unit tests on an R package in RStudio (or from a command line).

- But what are best practices for developing and running testthat unit tests for the custom functions in a drake workflow?

Any pointers to resources or examples would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practices for unit tests do not change much when `drake` enters the picture. Here are the main considerations.

1. If you are using `drake`, you are probably dealing with annoyingly long runtimes in your full pipeline. So one challenge is to construct tests that do not take forever. I recommend invoking your functions on a small dataset, a small number of iterations, or whatever will get the test done in a reasonable amount of time. You can run a lot of basic checks that way. To more thoroughly validate the answers that come from your functions, you can run an additional set of checks on the results of the `drake` pipeline.
2. If you are using `testthat`, you probably have your functions arranged in a package-like structure, or even a fully-fledged package, and you may even be loading your functions with `devtools::load_all()` or `library(yourPackage)`. If you load your functions this way instead of individually sourcing your function scripts, be sure to call [`expose_imports()`](https://docs.ropensci.org/drake/reference/expose_imports.html) before `make()` so `drake` can analyze the functions for dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, Will!

Reading between the lines, it seems you're suggesting that a repository that runs a drake workflow can also be an R package. Am I interpreting you correctly? If so, are there any resources for package/drake integration? (I'm not looking for info on R packages, as I have authored a few of them. Rather, info on having a "drake repository" also be a package.)

Thanks again for the excellent drake package!

Comment: I see the `drakepkg` package at https://github.com/tiernanmartin/drakepkg. Perhaps that is a good place to start.

Comment: Yup, I you're on the right track with `drakepkg`. There's also a brief mention of the major general best practices at https://books.ropensci.org/drake/projects.html#workflows-as-r-packages, but it's not much.

Comment: There are more examples in the wild, and I will come back and update this thread if I can find them. My own are locked down and company confidential.

Comment: Thanks again, Will! I think my next step is to convert my existing repository that uses drake to a package structure. I'll report here on any experiences/gotchas that aren't available elsewhere.